# How do I get multiple MySQL statements in one scheduled event?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do two statements in one scheduled event but it is not working. It wont do anything. Could you please help me figure out what is wrong?

```
delimiter |
CREATE EVENT resetTimeClockTimeToday 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2012-07-10 00:00:00' DO 
BEGIN 
   UPDATE timeclock.employees SET timeToday = 0; 
   UPDATE timeclock.punches SET missedOut = 1 WHERE timeOUT IS NULL; 
END|
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I restarted the MySQL service and it worked!

Comment: I doubt this was the case - more likely some SQL code changed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to correctly use a different delimiter, e.g.:

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `Daily Event`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `Daily event` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-03-06 00:30:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO
BEGIN

-- Newly due summary sheets
UPDATE          `summaries`
SET             `status` = 'DUE'
WHERE           `status` = 'OPEN'
AND             NOW() >= LAST_DAY(CONCAT(`year`, '-', `month`, '-01'));

-- Alert user that didn't clock out
INSERT INTO     `alerts` (`from`, `to`, `subject`, `message`)
SELECT          ....;

-- Alert manager that didn't clock out
INSERT INTO     `alerts` (`from`, `to`, `subject`, `message`)
SELECT          ....;

-- Alert for stale tickets
INSERT INTO     `alerts` (`from`, `to`, `subject`, `message`)
SELECT          ....;

END;
$$;
```

Comment: @eggyal Then the OP executed some other query for it to not work. Restarting MySQL isn't going to make any difference. I've said as much in a comment on the OP's answer.

Comment: Your answer says that he needs "to correctly use a different delimiter" (and then gives example code that's not particularly relevant to the question). I've pointed out that, in my opinion, the change of delimiter shown in the question is completely correct—and therefore that your answer is wrong.  Consequently I cannot see how your answer is helpful, which is what downvotes are intended to indicate. I'm sorry that you are upset by that.  For what it's worth, I have upvoted your comment on the OP's answer because I agree that something else has probably changed. But this answer is not correct.

Comment: @eggyal I'm not upset at all; although your rant seems excessive.

Comment: What rant?  I was explaining my downvote, since you said (one can only imagine sarcastically) that it was so "nice" on a "correct answer".